# в чём причина ошибки?JS

Tags: javascript

```js
let elm = document.querySelectorAll('.row div')
elm.map(addEventListener('click', divpress))
//"Uncaught TypeError: elm.map is not a function",
function divpress(){
    alert('ok')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elm.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', divpress));
```

Comment: тысячу раз ему давали пример с forEach.